# How to change the css of a dynamically added element?

Tags: jquery, dynamic-html

I am adding several divs with class "data_record" dynamically to the DOM.

I want each one to turn a colour when clicked and for the others to turn back to a white background.

Here is my code to do this after having successfully added the data_record elements...

```
$(document).on('click', ".data_record", function(event) {
    //turn all others white (this DOES NOT work!)
    $('.data_record').css('background','#ffffff');

    //turn the clicked element a different colour (this DOES work!)
    $(this).css('background', '#EDC580');
});
```

So how to I target dynamically added elements by their class?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/QQ52W/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `.css('background-color',value)` to set background color:

```
 $(document).on('click', ".data_record", function(event) {
//turn all others white (this now works!)
    $('.data_record').css('background-color','#ffffff');

//turn the clicked element a different colour (this DOES work!)
    $(this).css('background-color', '#EDC580');
});
```

Comment: So the code was kind of right but 'background' does not work for jQuery. Jquery needs the css to be more specific?

Comment: In which case why did the
    $(this).css('background', '#EDC580');
work?

Comment: @daktau:i could not reproduce it being not working. can you share the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

This should change the `background-color`:

```
$('.data_record').css('background-color','#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var n=0;
    while(n<10)
    {
        $("body").append("<div class=dataRecord>Height</div>");
        n++;
    }

    $(".dataRecord").on("click",function(event){
        var self=$(this);

         $(".dataRecord").css("color","black");
        self.css("color","white");
    });
```

Try the fiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/sgW77/1/

Comment: why would you iterate through datarecord? jQuery iterates automatically. Also OP wants background color not text color...